# Reference request: Partition function as a topological invariant of a QFT

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

I have read (mainly in the articles of Atiyah) that the partition function is the simplest topological invariant of a quantum field theory.

I have an arithmetic geometry background and know statistical physics quite well, but am a beginner in QFT. A reference for details on the above statement in mathematical language à la "Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians" would be highly appreciated.

A sketch of the ideas involved would be even nicer.

If this question is too simple or vague, please let me know - I will transfer it to SE.

Comment: But if you have read Atiyah's papers, then you should know that he himself defined what's a called now a functorial field theory in http://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/TQFT/At.pdf . In any case, I like the references https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/OldTQFTLectures.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9503002.pdf . A similar definition was also given by Segal for the conformal flavor https://www.math.upenn.edu/~blockj/scfts/segal.pdf.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the question is about. Is it about the definition of the partition function of a QFT? Is it about topological invariants of manifolds which can be realized as partition functions of TQFT? (More precisely, I am not sure what "topological invariant of a QFT" means, is it something invariant under deformation of the QFT, or something else?)

Comment: I agree with the comment of user25309. Perhaps you could give a citation to a particular claim in the literature that you are curious about.

Comment: @user40276 Thank you very much for references. This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one case where you might just want to go back to the original article that proved that a partition function is metric-independent and hence a topological invariant: Edward Witten, [Quantum field theory and the Jones polynomial](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178138) (1989) --- see page 361.

For a sketch of the idea, this [introduction](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jsvrvXPc4hIC&pg=PA25) by Marcos Marino seems useful (page 25+26).

Comment: Having browsed through that article myself, I believe it is not what the OP has asked for: he is looking for a rigorous text, *"in mathematical language à la 'Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians'"* - which Witten's article is *very far from* (really, why was he awarded the Fields Medal for that... thing?).

Comment: this is off-topic here, but if you want to know why Witten was awarded the Fields Medal, perhaps [Atiyah's appraisal](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/reinsch/phys105spr2014/files/Witten_Atiyah.pdf) is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. It gives an nice illustration of the idea. I will be a good exercise for me to translate it into the "mathematical language". Together with the references from user40276 this is exactly what I have been looking for.